# Export class as Node.js module in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amd

I'm familiar with the `export` keyword in TypeScript, and two canonical ways of exporting things from Node modules using TypeScript (of course, the TypeScript modules can be used as well, but they are even further from what I'm looking for):

```
export class ClassName { }
```

and a series of

```
export function functionName () { }
```

However, the way I usually write my modules, so that they are later imported as instantiable closures, is:

```
var ClassName = function () { };
ClassName.prototype.functionName = function () { };
module.exports = ClassName;
```

Is there a way I can do this using the TypeScript export syntax?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do that quite simply in TypeScript 0.9.0 :

```
class ClassName { 
    functionName () { }
}

export = ClassName;
```

Comment: Remove the `export` from the class definition and it works perfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: @BraedenP yeah sorry, forgot that :)

Comment: Damn, why I'm so stupid. I was using AMD modules with node for a while :facepalm:

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I export CommonJS (Node.js) modules with TypeScript:

**src/ts/user/User.ts**

```
export default class User {
  constructor(private name: string = 'John Doe',
              private age: number = 99) {
  }
}
```

**src/ts/index.ts**

```
import User from "./user/User";

export = {
  user: {
    User: User,
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "lib": ["ES6"],
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "outDir": "dist/commonjs",
    "removeComments": true,
    "rootDir": "src/ts",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES6"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "bower_components",
    "dist/commonjs",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**dist/commonjs/index.js (Compiled module entry point)**

```
"use strict";
const User_1 = require("./user/User");
module.exports = {
    user: {
        User: User_1.default,
    }
};
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

**dist/commonjs/user/User.js (Compiled User class)**

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
class User {
    constructor(name = 'John Doe', age = 72) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
exports.default = User;
//# sourceMappingURL=User.js.map
```

**Testing code (test.js)**

```
const MyModule = require('./dist/commonjs/index');
const homer = new MyModule.user.User('Homer Simpson', 61);
console.log(`${homer.name} is ${homer.age} years old.`); // "Homer Simpson is 61 years old."
```